# Change the column value to sinle format

Tags: pandas-datareader

My existing data frame having have date column with different date time

```
11-07-2016 10:54:27
14-07-2016 15:26:06
11/7/2016 8:00
14/7/2016 19:52
```

I want to change all the values into a same date format

Comment: explain more...

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried (=code). Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].